# Qual a diferença entre um compilador e executável do Windows e do Linux

Tags: linux, windows, compilação, .exe, linkagem

Quando se compila um programa simples para Linux, o compilador gera um executável que só funciona no Linux, mas quando se compila o Mesmo código com um compilador para Windows ele gera um executável que só funciona para Windows. Oque eu quero saber é qual diferença do processo de compilação nos 2 sistemas operacionais ?

Se o código é o mesmo, porque o resultado final é diferente ? Em qual parte da compilação que começa as diferenças ? é na parte da linkagem ? e porque existem essas diferenças ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32117572/why-does-a-linux-compiled-program-not-work-on-windows

Comment: Entendi, mas bem que alguém poderia responder em português para ajudar a popular a versão brasileira do StackOverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta resposta é simplista, mas tenta dar uma ideia. Imagine que os programas são uma lista de solicitações para fazer algo.

Assim como num restaurante onde voce faz o pedido informando que quer bem passado, com ou sem cebolas, ..., isto é só o pedido (seu programa). Quem vai realmente preparar o prato (o kernel do sistema operacional) está na cozinha tenta preparar de acordo com o seu pedido (o programa).

Você só comerá o que quer se falar a mesma do cozinheiro.

O cozinheiro do linux fala ELF e o do windows fala PE. Então normalmente um não entende os pedidos feitos para o outro.

Mas tem alguns que são bilíngues e conseguem entender outros formatos. Um projeto muito legal é o [wine](https://www.winehq.org/) que roda executáveis do windows no linux (por vezes com performance melhor que no próprio windows).

Então é só uma questão de entender o idioma para se comunicar com o sistema operacional.

Aqui tem um link para alguns [tipos de formato de executável](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Comparaci%C3%B3n_de_formatos_de_archivos_ejecutables) (em espanhol, mas acho que dá para ter uma idéia que tem um monte)